# How do add a keyboard in SuperTuxKart2?

Tags: keyboard

I just build a controler for [SuperTuxKart2](https://supertuxkart.net/), (and I have done this in the past) but SuperTuxKart2 doesn’t seem to recognize my device. Or any multiplayer option for that matter.

It says users must use the “select” key to join the game, but man, I don’t know what that means at all. Where is the select key on the keyboard? How do I add a controller? What is the select key?

I just dont know these things. When I build a custom controller a few years ago, it just worked, when ever I plugged it in.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, the controler is based on a [Teensy 2.0](https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy.html) USB development board, and my SuperTuxKart2 version is: SuperTuxKart, 0.9.2.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995537/what-is-the-select-key